# Unwanted space between linline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I have following code:
In HTML

```
 ​<div id="first" >​</div>  
 <div id="second"></div>
```

In CSS

```
​#first,#second {  
    background-color: red;  
    display: inline-block;  
    width:50px;  
    height:50px;  
    margin:0px;  
    padding:0px;  
    border: 0px;  
}​
```

I observe a space between the divs which I am not able to remove. Any help? Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4NQEm/) to jsfiddle source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the whitespace you have included while formatting your HTML. You can set the font size of the parent to zero to fix this.

```
#container{
    font-size:0;
}
```

An alternative approach is to format your HTML like this:

```
​<div id="first" >​<  
/div><div id="second"></div
/div>...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NQEm/1/

Comment: This is unreliable, as some browsers have a setting for the minimum allowable font size.

Answer (score 1):

The space is there in the HTML, so it will be there in the output. Try shoving the `</div><div id="second">` together with no space between them.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want a completely messed up HTML to avoid spaces between `inline-block` displayed divs, you can use HTML comments to connect the divs, [as I've described in a more exhaustive way here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776780/1654265)

```
    ​<div id="first" >​</div><!--  
 --><div id="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove space between two divs you need to set margin-left property of second div negative pixels check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4NQEm/5/) or

```
#second
{
    margin-left:-4px;
}
```